# How to plot learning curve by two data sets (one for train, another for test)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Since I use one oversampling data (1000) to train the random forest model and use the original data (57) as the test set, I define the two data as X,y (1000) and X1,y1 (57).Can someone tell me another method that can plot the right learning curve in two data sets?

I tried to use sklearn function "learning_curve"to plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

df = pd.read_csv(data1)
df_data = pd.DataFrame(df)
X = df_data.drop(labels=['target'],axis=1).values
y = df_data['target'].values

df1 = pd.read_csv(data2)
df_data1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
X1 = df_data1.drop(labels=['target'],axis=1).values
y1 = df_data1['target'].values

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scoreX = learning_curve(RandomForestClassifier(), X, y, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, train_sizes=np.linspace(0.6, 1, 100))

train_sizeX, train_scoreX, test_scores = learning_curve(RandomForestClassifier(), X1, y1, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1, train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1, 50))

train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean, '--', color="#111111",  label="Training score")
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, color="#111111", label="Test score")

plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_mean - train_std, train_mean + train_std, color="#DDDDDD")
plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_mean - test_std, test_mean + test_std, color="#DDDDDD")

plt.title("Random Forest Learning Curve")
plt.xlabel("Dataset Size"), plt.ylabel("Accuracy"), plt.legend(loc="best")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

learning_curve function in sklearn cannot be used to draw the learning curve because they have different dimension
`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (50,)`

Answer (score 0):

The second plot is using the variable `train_sizes`. Should be `train_sizeX` instead.